How to combine two union types?
type A = 1 | 2 | 3
type B = 4 | 5 & A
type C = A & 4 | 5
type D = A & (4 | 5)
type E = (4 | 5) & A

type X = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

typeX is the result I expected.
TypeB and TypeC are the attempts I made, but they all failed.
What is the correct approach?

@jcalz Thanks, you are right. You can post this as an answer.

If you have the union
type A = 1 | 2 | 3

and want a union with more members like
type B = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

You can replace 1 | 2 | 3 by A and get
type B = A | 4 | 5

That is, you want a union of unions.  There's no reason to use the intersection operator unless you're trying to remove members.
Playground link to code
